# $Y = \vert Z \vert$ with $Z ∼ N(0, 1)$ has continuous distribution despite not being differentiable at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, normal-distribution, absolute-value

I encountered the following example:

> (Folded Normal). Let $Y = \vert Z \vert$ with $Z ∼ N(0, 1)$. The distribution of $Y$ is called a Folded Normal with parameters $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma^2 = 1$. At first sight, $Y$ may seem tricky to deal with since the absolute value function is not differentiable at $0$ (due to its sharp corner), but $Y$ has a perfectly valid continuous distribution.
>
> $$E(Y) = E \vert Z \vert = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \vert z \vert \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2} \ dz = 2 \int_0^\infty z \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2} \ dz = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}.$$

How is it possible that, despite the fact that the absolute value function is not differentiable at $0$ (due to its sharp corner), $Y$ still has a continuous distribution? Is this not in violation of the theory behind integration in real analysis?

Thank you.

Comment: How is it possible?  Differentiability and continuity are different properties, and a function can be continuous without being differentiable.

Comment: @nomen But doesn't integration require differentiability?

Comment: @DomFomello Nope, differentiation require differentiability. Integration doesn't even require continuity (think the step function, for example)

Comment: @DonThousand But integration (antiderivatives) and differentiation are analogues, right? So, although you're probably correct, the explanation isn't very convincing.

Comment: @DomFomello Well, they are "inverses", in an extremely loose way, rather than analogues.

Comment: @DonThousand Yes, "inverses"; that's a better way of putting it.

Comment: @DomFomello So why would you assume that integrals need as strict conditions to be well-defined as derivatives? Do we assume that the result of differentiation is differentiable?

Comment: @DonThousand Hmm, I presumed that, since differentiation and antiderivatives are inverses, then they likely share a very similar set of conditions to be defined. But I guess I was wrong.

Comment: @DomFomello Be careful calling them inverses. Yes, the operations seem to behave like inverses, but they lack several important properties of actual inverses.

Comment: @DonThousand Yes, my apologies. So, in that case, what are the minimum requirements for an integral to be defined? Piecewise continuity?

Comment: Depends on the definition. The standard definition is the Lesbegue integration, in which case it is defined if all sets of the form $\{x\mid f(x)>t\}$ for any $t$ are measurable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105015/discussion-between-dom-fomello-and-don-thousand).

Comment: @DonThousand "... for non-negative functions $f$"?